# JavaFX task/thread not filling tableview consistently

Tags: java, javafx

So, i need to fill a Table View using a JavaFX thread but the table is being filled only ~70% of time. I am looking at my code and i really can't find where the problem comes from, my guess is that the task is somehow being executed before the data is successfully retrieved/processed from db. Thanks is advance :)

```
private Executor exec;
private ObservableList<User> cellData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
.
.
.
public void fillTable(HashMap<String,Object> whereClause){
        Task<List<User>> task = new Task<List<User>>(){
            @Override
            public ObservableList<User> call(){
                cellData.clear();
                cellData.addAll(userRepository.getAll(whereClause));
                userId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userID"));
                userName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userName"));
                userMail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userMail"));
                userPhone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userPhone"));
                isAdmin.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                    String isAdminAsString = cellData.getValue().isAdmin() ? "Admin" : "Medic";
                    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(isAdminAsString);
                });
                isDeleted.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                    String isActiveUser = cellData.getValue().isDeleted() ? "No" : "Yes";
                    return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(isActiveUser);
                });
                logger.info("Cell values set");
                return cellData;
            }
        };
        exec.execute(task);
        task.setOnFailed(e -> System.out.println(task.getException().getMessage()));
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> userTable.setItems((ObservableList<User>) task.getValue()));
        logger.info("Fill user Table Task executed");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give enough context for a proper, fully confident answer, but my guess is you're encountering issues relating to threads. JavaFX is not thread-safe; using the wrong thread to update the UI can lead to *undefined behavior*, such as the data only appearing ~70% of the time. There's an important rule in JavaFX that you must **always** follow:

- Never read or write the state of objects that are connected—directly or indirectly—to a live scene graph on a thread other than the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

Your code does not follow this rule. Inside the `call` method of your `Task` you are structurally modifying `cellData` and setting the `cellValueFactory` of various `TableColumn`s. This leads to said objects being modified by whatever thread is executing the `Task`. If the `Executor` is any hint, that thread is definitely not the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

I'm not sure why you're setting the `cellValueFactory` of your `TableColumn`s inside the `call` method in the first place. The cell value factory is configuration that only needs to be done once—when you create the `TableColumn` (or shortly thereafter). In other words, configuring the cell value factory in the `call` method is wrong not just because it happens on a background thread but also because it happens each time you execute the `Task`. Remove the set-the-cell-value-factory code from the `call` method and move it, if needed, to where you're creating the `TableColumn`s. If you're using FXML, and the `TableColumn`s are created for you and injected, then the controller's `initialize` method is a good place for this sort of configuration.

Your `cellData` list is connected to your `TableView`, if not at first then definitely after the first successful execution of your `Task`. Modifying `cellData` on a background thread will notify the `TableView` of those changes on the same thread (listeners are invoked on the same thread that made the change). The easy solution is to have your `Task` return a *new* `List` and then update the `TableView` if successful.

```
Task<List<User>> task = new Task<List<User>>() {
    @Override protected List<User> call() throws Exception {
        return userRepository.getAll(whereClause);
    }
});
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> userTable.getItems().setAll(task.getValue()));
task.setOnFailed(event -> task.getException().printStackTrace());
exec.execute(task);
```

The `setAll` method of `ObservableList` will first clear the list then add all the elements of the given collection (or array). This is somewhat more efficient than calling `clear` followed by `addAll` because it results in only one change event. Also, if you want to continue using `cellData` you can, assuming you've previously set it as your table's items; just use `cellData.setAll(task.getValue())` instead.

---

Regarding the use of:

```
task.setOnSucceeded(e -> userTable.setItems((ObservableList<User>) task.getValue()));
```

Since you clearly expect an `ObservableList<User>` to be returned, you should be using a `Task<ObservableList<User>>` instead of a `Task<List<User>>`. This will mean `getValue()` returns `ObservableList<User>` and thus the cast becomes unneeded. However, if you follow the advice above, then this is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you! This explained me a lot, i don't have very much java experience. Now it's now working consistently :)